# CakePHP 3 Add Action Routes to Index or Returns Null

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to pass JSON into an Add() action of my controller but the response I get is either a response from the Index() action or "null" depending on entries in my routes.php (shown below).

I'm using Firefox plugin RESTClient to test/pass json to my actions:

**Method: POST**

**URL:** http://MyApp/notes.json (my understanding is this should call Add action based on [cakephp docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#creating-restful-routes) )

JSON:

```
{
"post_id":"123",
"note":"hello world"
}
```

When I have the following in my routes.php, the response is "null"

```
Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {
  $routes->extensions(['json']);
  $routes->resources('Notes');
```

Removing `$routes->resources('Notes');` from this scope returns a response from the index action and all items in the Notes model are returned in the response.

Furthermore, when I implement this through Crud.Add in an api prefix, I get valid results. That being said trying to understand what I have incorrect in my routes.php or add action that could be causing the null or routing to index action.

Add Action:

```
public function add() 
{
    $note = $this->Notes->newEntity();
      if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $note = $this->Notes->patchEntity($note, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Notes->save($note)) {
            $message = 'Saved';
        } else {
                        $message = 'Error';
        }
    }
    $this->set('_serialize', ['note', 'message']);
}
```

Routes.php:

```
<?php

use Cake\Core\Plugin;
use Cake\Routing\Router;

Router::defaultRouteClass('DashedRoute');
Router::extensions(['json'], ['xml']);

Router::prefix('api',function($routes) {
    $routes->extensions(['json','xml']);
    $routes->resources('Notes');
});

Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {
      $routes->extensions(['json']);
    $routes->resources('Notes');

    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);

    $routes->connect('/pages/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display']);

    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});

Plugin::routes();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set any variables for the view, other than serialization options, so you get `null` because there's nothing to serialize, ie you are missing something like

```
$this->set(compact('note', 'message'));
```

in your action.

And without the resource routes a request to `/notes` maps to the index action of the `Notes` controller, because that's how fallback routes are connected, no action = index action.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Views > JSON And XML Views > Using Data Views with the Serialize Key](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-data-views-with-the-serialize-key)**
- **[Cookbook > Routing > Fallbacks Method](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#fallbacks-method)**

Comment: uggh!! I can not believe I missed that. staring me right in face, thank you!!